# Trying to Run this code using POM but got error. selenium version= 4.8.3

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, browser-automation

Trying to Run this code using POM but got error.  selenium version= 4.8.3

**Test Case File:**

```
\`import time

from selenium import webdriver
from Functions import definedFunctions
from locators import Locators
from data import form

class New():

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
    
    def setup(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("https://demoqa.com/")
        
    def Text_box(self):
        elm = definedFunctions(self.driver)
        lc = Locators
        data = form
        
        elm.click_on_button(lc.var)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.text_box)
        elm.send_keys_by_xpaths(lc.full_name, data.NAME)
        elm.send_keys_by_xpaths(lc.email, data.email)
        elm.send_keys_by_xpaths(lc.curr_address, data.address_cur)
        elm.send_keys_by_xpaths(lc.per_address, data.address_per)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.submit_btn)
    
    def Check_box(self):
        elm = definedFunctions(self.driver)
        lc = Locators
        data = form
        elm.click_on_button(lc.check_box)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.plus_btn)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.check1)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.check2)
        elm.click_on_button(lc.check3)
        time.sleep(10)

\`obj = New()
obj.setup()
obj.Text_box()
obj.Check_box()\`\`
```

**Function File**

```
\`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class definedFunctions:
def __init__(self, driver):
self.driver = driver

    def click_on_button(self, xpath):
        click = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", click)
    
    def send_keys_by_xpaths(self, xpath, key):
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))).send_keys(key)`
```

**Error occurred**

"
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\TestCases.py", line 46, in <module>
obj.Text_box()
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\TestCases.py", line 24, in Text_box
elm.click_on_button(lc.var)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\Functions.py", line 11, in click_on_button
click = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 50).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\New folder\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 86, in until
value = method(self._driver)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\New folder\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\expected_conditions.py", line 152, in _predicate
return _element_if_visible(driver.find_element(*locator))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Answer (score 0):

Check your "driver" parameter. Currently the error states, that a
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'.

> _element_if_visible(driver.find_element(*locator)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_element'

Looking at these lines of code we see the object is "driver".

> driver.find_element(*locator)

So there is no valid driver provided.

With options provided it should work.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

source:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/options/